# Email Format Ever Exclude the Period

Tags: validation, email

Do all emails have a `.` in them? like sample@sample`.`com or are there any emails that ever follow this format? `sample@sample` Please provide proof of your answer.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/827263

Comment: Did you Google "email without dot"? Because the first link (for me) is to a stackoverflow thread on how an email address without a dot in the domain is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, There is no restriction on having a `dot` in the email (as long as we are considering the syntax).

Thats why even `HTML5` validation of email allows emails like `hello@world`.

Since domain part can also be an `IP address`, emails like `batman@[192.168.1.1]` or `ironman@localhost` are also valid.

See [Proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Domain_part)